# convert unsigned long to wchar_t

Tags: wchar-t

I want to copy an unsigned value to `wchar_t` array.
and using this

```
unsigned long lValue = <value>//value 

wchar_t wszBuffer[256] = L"";
::swprintf_s( wszBuffer, _countof(wszBuffer), wszFormat, lValue );
```

it doesn't work for long values greater than 2147483647.
Whats the solution for this?

Comment: What is the value of `wszFormat`?  I'd expect `"%lu"`.

Comment: Thank you ..this was the mistake. I was using %d.

Answer (score 0):

Think wchar_t is saved as 2 16bit int as a UTF-16 format.
Would not use it unless you had to. The structure below stores any charter in a single uint32_t(a 32 bit integer in c++).
But if you need an unsigned long(64 bit integer) array,
I would create one with a vector like this:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> array;
```

following for 32 bit or less

```
 full file location: 
 https://github.com/NashBean/iBS_LIB/blob/master/iBS_Header.h

//-----------------------------------------------
//uchar = uint made to hold any char of the world
//-----------------------------------------------
 struct uchar
{
    uchar():value(0){}; 
    uchar(int v):value((uint32_t)v){}; 
    uchar(long v):value((uint32_t)v){}; 
    uchar(uint32_t v):value(v){}; 
    uchar(uint v):value(v.get()){}; 
    uchar(char v):value((uint32_t)v){}; 
    uchar(uchar const &v):value(v.value){}; 
    uchar(wchar_t wch):value(decode(wch)){}; 

    uchar& operator=(int unicode){ 
     set((uint32_t)unicode); 
return *this; };
    uchar& operator=(uint32_t unicode){ set(unicode); 
return *this; };
    uchar& operator=(uint unicode) { set(unicode.get()); 
return *this; };
    uchar& operator=(char ch) { set((uint32_t)ch); return *this; };
    uchar& operator=(uchar uch) { set(uch.get()); return *this; };
    uchar& operator=(wchar_t wch) { set(decode(wch).get()); 
return *this; };// use of Uchar.h

    bool operator==(int i) { return (value == i); };
    bool operator==(uint32_t unicode) { return (value == unicode); };
    bool operator==(uint unicode) { return (value == unicode); };
    bool operator==(char c) { return (value == c); };
    bool operator==(uchar uch) { return (value == uch.value); };

    uint32_t get() { return value.get(); };
    void set(uint32_t v) { value = v; };

private:    
    uint value;
};
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.